# Give colname of object in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, search, lookup

i do have a very easy question, but can't find an easy solution (dunno why)

So I would like to know how r could let me know in what column an object is.
 e.g if we take the iris dataset I know there should be "setosa" somewhere in it, but I would like that the command returns me the column-name ("Species").

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sapply` to loop over the `list` check if there are `any` 'setosa' and use that to subset the column names

```
names(iris)[sapply(iris, function(x) any(x == 'setosa'))]
#[1] "Species"
```

---

Or using `select_if`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
     select_if(~ any(. == 'setosa')) %>%
     names
#[1] "Species"
```

It may be better to have another condition to check only non-numeric columns

```
iris %>%
     select_if(~ is.factor(.) && any(. == 'setosa')) %>%
     names
```

Comment: Hi akrun, WOW Thank you very much for your fast and nice answer(s). It work exactly as intended and I'll use this! I just thought there would be a simple preinstalled function for what seems as kind of an elementar function. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another base R option, admittedly no faster than [@akrun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61090464).

```r
sapply(iris, function(x) 'setosa' %in% x)
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE         TRUE 

names(iris)[sapply(iris, function(x) 'setosa' %in% x)]
# [1] "Species"
```

Comment: Thank you this is also very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here are two base R options.

Using `Filter` :

```
names(Filter(function(x) any(x == 'setosa'), iris))
#[1] "Species"
```

Using `colSums` :

```
names(iris)[colSums(iris == 'setosa') > 0]
#[1] "Species"
```